# Reload a UIWebView from a sperate view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a tabbed application, on the first tab a UiWebView is loaded when the application is run, the second tab contains settings, the user can change the settings and click a 'Save' button.

When the user updates the settings and presses 'Save', I want the UiWebview on the first tab to be reloaded.

I have searched various terms to try and find a answer but not much luck, there must be a simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to the `UIWebView` and reload it like so:

```
UIWebView *webView = [...];
[webView reload];
```

I expect the `UIWebView` is owned by some `ViewController`. It would make sense for that `ViewController` to implement this code and expose a method for external classes to instruct it to perform the refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Add `reloadWebView` method to the controller that owns `UIWebView`:

```
+(void) reloadWebView
{
    [self.webView reload];
}
```

From your other controller, call this method:

```
[self.tabBar.viewControllers[0] reloadWebView];
```

where `0` is your tab index.

Comment: When adding the method, my webview isn't showing up when typing self.webSchedule get a implicit conversion error.

Comment: That's because you need to add an outlet to your webview from your view controller. Google "add an outlet in xcode" to find out how.

Comment: Well, then you should call `[self.webSchedule0 reload]`.